# How do I set the Quick Access shortcuts for all users on a Terminal Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, terminal-services, windows-10-quick-access

I have run into a problem. On our Terminal Server (Windows Server 2019) with 25 users, the Quick Access shortcuts of Desktop, Downloads, and Documents are somehow set to:

C:\Users\Default\Desktop, C:\Users\Default\Downloads, and C:\Users\Default\Documents

instead of the expected:

C:\Users%username%\ directory.

Now the problem is that users are saving their file in the Default directory and it shows up on the desktops of all users. Can you please suggest a way to sort this out and reset the Quick Access shortcuts to a %username% directory quickly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did this happen suddenly or has it always been like that? Sounds like the default profile is messed up and each new user is getting bad settings. You could fix this with a logon script. But users shouldn’t be able to write to the default folders at all. Are you letting your user have admin permissions on your terminal server? You’re just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Appleoddity This has happened after we created an Active Directory. Users certainly do not have admin permissions. Any suggestions on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: My preference would be to find out what happened and then go from there. Without knowing what caused this it’s hard to know the right way to solve it and the impact of it. Did you do some type of folder redirection with your group policies? The simplest thing sounds like a logon script or group policy folder redirection to change the path of the user folders. But then you also need to consider the data for the users and if it will affect the status of the default profile which needs to be setup properly as well for future users.

Comment: @Appleoddity The user folders are intact, their paths have not changed. It's only the Quick Access toolbar in which this has occurred. I want to fix these QA shortcuts and reset the Default directory. Does that sound good to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the quick access list to default you can run the following command from the logged in user’s command line:

```
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*
```

First, see if this fixes the issue.

If it does, you can have the users run this command manually. Or you could run it in a logon script, or you could use group policy preferences to delete this folder.

The problem is how to make sure it doesn’t run more than once and continually reset the quick access list. My preference would be to create a batch file with this command in it, within the batch file, you can put some logic in so that it runs only once. Perhaps, checking if a file exists that the batch file creates after the first run, making it abort after subsequent runs. Then schedule the batch script to run on logon using a group policy logon script. When everybody is confidently fixed, you can remove the logon script policy and be done.

Comment: The command worked. Since the number of users is just 25. I don't mind going into each user and running it once. However, the problem is that I created a new user for testing. It had the same issue. What do you think should be done to make it right?

Comment: @WishIWasACoder Delete the contents of that same folder under the “Default” user profile. When a new user is created they pick up the settings from the default user profile. Just do it through file explorer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Appleoddity, it has worked.